# Какие лучше использовать PHP Framework`и для сайта тестирования

Tags: php, framework

Сайт по тестированию студентов. Есть личный кабинет проходящего тест и человека, который создаёт/редактирует/удаляет вопросы (хранятся в phpmyadmin(mySQL)). Какой PHP фреймворк большего всего подойдёт под данный сайт?

Comment: любой подойдет. такие простые вещи можно сделать на любом фреймворке

Answer (score -2):

1. В phpmyadmin ничего не хранится - это просто интерфейс для работы с БД
2. Насколько знаю - в фреймворках нет готовых личных кабинетов, в любом случае писать придется
3. Ну и по теме фреймворков - посоветовал бы CakePHP и Laravel. Первый более прост в освоении, зато второй довольно удобен и предоставляет массу возможностей. Если есть время разбираться, тогда взял бы Symphony

Comment: навскидку codeigniter, yii и тд. Имхо стоит выбирать тот, у которого больше документация (+на русском), а также популярность (так как будет куча ответов по вопросам как тут на SO).

Comment: @Jean-Claude никогда не ставил наличие русской документации в приоритет. Тот же Laravel и Симфония довольно неплохо задокументированы, глупо отрицать. С Codelighter мой косяк, забыл о нем, а YII, особенно второй в плане документации даже до ларавела не дотягивает, я уже молчу о востребованности где-либо, кроме СНГ. Посмотрите на том же Upwork количество требуемых разрабов на yii и на других фреймворках